# Gauss Elimination "Object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Tags: python, typeerror

Basically, I'm trying to code the `Gauss Elimination(Foward)` method, but, when executed, Python raises an exception saying: `"Object has no attribute '__getitem__'"` when the subtraction between 2 lists occurs.

The complete stacktrace is:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File line 35, in <module>
>     b=a.GaussForward()
> File line 29, in GaussForward 
>     self.a[index][w]=self.a[index][w]-aux[i][w]
> TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'getitem'
> ```

I'll post the code below.

```
class TestGauss():
    a=[]
    def __init__(self,A):
        self.a=A
    def __getitem__(self,i):
        return self.a[i]

    def __setitem__(self,i,value):
        self.a[i]=value

    def GaussForward(self):
        pivo=0.0
        fact=0.0
        aux=[]
        for i in range(len(self.a)):
            pivo=self.a[i][i]
            for j in range(i+1,len(self.a[0])):
                fact=self.a[j][i]/float(pivo)
                print fact
                for k in range(len(self.a[0])):
                    self.a[i][k]*=fact
                for w in range(len(self.a[0])):
                    aux=self.a[i]
                    if i+1<len(self.a[0]):
                        index=i+1
                        self.a[index][w]=self.a[index][w]-aux[i][w]

        print self.a
```

Comment: It is helpful to include the entire stacktrace in your question.

Comment: oh, my bad. Here is the stacktrace(i think).Traceback (most recent call last):
  File line 35, in <module>
    b=a.GaussForward()
  File line 29, in GaussForward
    self.a[index][w]=self.a[index][w]-aux[i][w]
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies with `aux[i][w]`. Since you set `aux=self.a[i]`, `aux` is a flat list (ie. not a list of lists) and thus when you try to access `aux[i][w]`, you're trying to index `self.a[i][i][w]` which is not correct. I think you meant to do this:

```
self.a[index][w]=self.a[index][w]-aux[w]
```